# Changing cofinalities above supercompact cardinals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

> **Question.** Suppose $\kappa$ is a supercompact cardinal and $\lambda > \kappa$
> is measurable (or even larger large cardinal if necessary).
> Is there a set generic extension of the universe in which $\kappa$
> remains supercompact, $\lambda$ is preserved and $cf(\lambda)=\omega?$

**Remark 1.** By Gitik-Shelah indestructibility result, if supercompact cardinal is replaced with strong cardinal, then the answer is yes.

**Remark 2**. If we require that the forcing preserves $\lambda^+,$
then the answer is no, as it is shown by Yair.

**Remark 3**. In [A note on sequences witnessing singularity - following Magidor-Sinapova](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Egitik/witnessingseq.pdf), Gitik has conjectured the following:

> **Conjecture**. Suppose that
>
> 1. $V ⊆ W$ models of ZFC with same ordinals,
> 2. $κ$ is a regular cardinal in $V$,
> 3. $cof(κ) = ω$ in $W$,
> 4. $\aleph_1^V=\aleph_1^W,$
> 5. $V, W$ agree about a final segment of cardinals.
>
> Then there is a subclass $V′$ of $V$ which is a model of $ZFC$, agree with $V$ about a final segment
> of cardinals, and there is a sequence witnessing singularity of $κ$ (in $W$) which is generic over
> $V′$
> for either Namba, Woodin tower or Prikry type forcing.

Assuming this conjecture, it seems quite plausible that the answer to the question might be no in general.

---

**Edition.** I realized that the question has connection with recent work of Woodin:

**Theorem.** Assume $\kappa$ is an extendible cardinal. If Woodin's $HOD$-conjecture holds, then we can not change the cofinality of some large cardinal $\lambda > \kappa$, preserving the supercompactness of $\kappa,$ by set forcing without collapsing $\lambda.$

Comment: Supercompact can be made immune for $\kappa$-directed closed forcings, unfortunately those are proper, and a proper forcing cannot change cofinality without collapsing cardinals.

Comment: I think that if you allow class forcings then Woodin's stationary tower (with height $\delta = On$, assuming "$On$ is Woodin") can get you the desired situation. By forcing below $S^\lambda_\omega$, the critical point of the embedding $j\colon V\to M$ is $\lambda$, $\text{cf }\lambda = \omega$, and therefore $\kappa$ remains supercompact in $M$. Using the closure properties of $M$, the same holds in $V[G]$.

Comment: That's quite a conjecture.

Comment: Did you realize this by reading the recent review paper about the HOD conjecture? Because I reviewed it recently and felt something similar. But the question is what happens if the HOD conjecture is in fact false, and it is possible to have a dichotomy. Can you still *force* something like this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I realized it after looking at some slide talks by Woodin. The point is that HOD conjecture gives us weak extender model $N$ for $\kappa$ is supercompact and we have $\kappa$-covering between $N$ and $V$ and $N$ and $V[G]$, so the same between $V$ and $V[G]$. This implies the result. Surprisingly many problems I face in these days are connected to Woodin's work and I have to learn his work.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani : How do you know that N is a weak extender model for $V[G]$?

Comment: I recently asked @YairHayut the same question in an email.  He showed me an argument of Magidor showing that the strong compactness of $\kappa$ must be destroyed.

Comment: @MonroeEskew May you please give the details of the argument, maybe in an answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such forcing that preserves $\lambda^+$. Since $\lambda$ is measurable, $2^{<\lambda} = \lambda$ and therefore $\square_{\lambda,\lambda}$ holds in $V$. Since $\lambda^{+}$ is preserved, the same sequence will witness that there is still a weak square at $\lambda$ in the generic extension. But weak square fails at singular cardinals of small cofinality above a supercompact cardinal, so $\kappa$ cannot be supercompact in the generic extension.

In fact, a theorem of Dzamonja and Shelah shows that if you change the cofinality of an inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$ while preserving $\lambda^+$, there is even a $\square_{\lambda,\omega}$ sequence in the generic extension.